# javascript simple slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my slider to show "slide 1" after "slide 3" and not that after "slide 3" you are forced to use the return or previous button. I am a leak in javascript so I was wondering if someone could help me out for a sec ;)

And I was wondering how to make this one a width of 100% so it is more or less responsive :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Your code from above goes here
       var sliderWidth = 1280;
       var slider = $('#slidiemain');
       var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
       slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);

       var currentSlide = 1;

       $('a.prev1').click(function () {
           if (currentSlide > 1) {
               $('#slidiemain').animate({
                   left: '+=' + sliderWidth
               }, 700);
               currentSlide -= 1;
           }
       });

        $('a.next1').click(function () {
            if (currentSlide < sliderCount) {
                $('#slidiemain').animate({
                   left: '-=' + sliderWidth
               }, 700);
               currentSlide += 1;
           }
   });
});
```

Comment: Is this a plugin? If so which?

Comment: @RyanS its a simple plugin I found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the slideshow plugin you are using, but this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Your code from above goes here
       var sliderWidth = $( window ).width(); // Get the width of browser window
       var slider = $('#slidiemain');
       var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
       slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);

       var currentSlide = 1;

       $('a.prev1').click(function () {
           if (currentSlide > 1) {
               $('#slidiemain').animate({
                   left: '+=' + sliderWidth
               }, 700);
               currentSlide -= 1;
           }
       });

        $('a.next1').click(function () {
            if (currentSlide < sliderCount) {
                $('#slidiemain').animate({
                   left: '-=' + sliderWidth
               }, 700);
               currentSlide += 1;
           }
           else 
           {
                $('#slidiemain').animate({left: '+=' + (2*sliderWidth)}, 1);
                currentSlide = 1;
           }
   });
});
```

Comment: Its a simple content slider that I found and use to simply slide some text in to show for example client testimonials, however I am trying the code and somehow the "prev" button is not working anymore.

Comment: We need to know the name of the slider plugin.

Comment: i'm sorry, have no idea. I found it here on stack overflow and adjusted it to my website. No plugin installed for this one.

Comment: Ok, there's no trivial way to have a content slider without a plugin.
You should check your page for something like: '<script src="js/mystery_slider.js"></script>'

Comment: I hear you, but the only things that are in my html page are a link to jquery and the code above.